# Unable to view or edit etc/apt/sources.list

Tags: apt, 14.04, nano

I am trying to follow these instructions to permit new updates of an opensource GIS software program to take place on my Ubuntu: http://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/alldownloads.html#ubuntu

I used nano to add the following lines:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install qgis python-qgis
sudo apt-get install qgis-plugin-grass
```

only to discover that sudo is "not known" and caused an error.  When I tried to reopen the sources.list file I get a blank screen in the terminal (below).  Please, please advise.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct. Generally, things are now written individually into their own file under [`/etc/apt/sources.list.d`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10409235/creating-a-file-inside-etc-apt-sources-list-d). However, if you check [QGIS Installers](http://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/alldownloads.html#ubuntu) again - there is a ppa you might try,

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install qgis python-qgis qgis-plugin-grass
```

Comment: Thanks, it appears using the ppa would work, but I still cannot get it to run until I remove the lines of code I added to sources.list file.  Any idea why I was able to add the lines and now I cannot even see the text?

Comment: On my system `cat /etc/apt/sources.list` produces an empty file.

Comment: got it, see @avinashraj 's comment

Answer (score 2):

Path you gave on the nano is totally wrong. It's not `etc/apt/sources.list`, it's `/etc/apt/sources.list`. You forget the `/` symbol before `etc`. The below command will open `/etc/apt/sources.list` file through nano editor,

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

If you gave the file path wrongly, nano will open an empty window like above.

Comment: ok,that was it.

Comment: I answered your question after reading the title only "Unable to view or edit etc/apt/sources.list". Still now i didn't read the content.

Answer (score 0):

I may be mistaken - please correct me if I am. From your text above, it appears that you are adding the lines

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install qgis python-qgis
sudo apt-get install qgis-plugin-grass
```

to your /etc/apt/sources.list file.  This is incorrect - the 'sudo apt-get...'  lines are commands which should be typed into a terminal to ask Ubuntu to fetch the packages into your operating system. Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> to open a terminal for this purpose.  The sudo command will ask for your password before proceeding.